# Random Number generator not working, out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, bluej

I have just started to code using this program, so go easy on me. :) So I try to add random variables to an arraylist, but they keep coming out to 0. I think it may be because it is maybe not adding anything to the list? How do I call the add2array method in the other class(the class below)?

```
public class myClass
{
  // instance variables 
  public Random r;
  public Random t;
  public Random o;
  public int randomR;
  public int randomT;
  public int randomO;
  public ArrayList <Integer> myArray;

  /**
   * Constructor for objects of class 
   */
  public myClass()
  {
    r = new Random();
    t = new Random();
    o = new Random();
    int randomR = (r.nextInt(10));
    int randomT = (t.nextInt(10));
    int randomO = (o.nextInt(10));
    myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }
  public void add2Array()
  {
    myArray.add(randomR); //myArray[0] is first random number
    myArray.add(randomT); //myArray[1] is second random number
    myArray.add(randomO); //myArray[2] is third random number
  }
}
```

Then there is this code in another class. I try to call printArray in the class, and it says there is an out of bounds exception.

```
public class myClass2
{
  Arraylist<myClass> myArray;


  public myClass2()
  {
    myArray = new ArrayList<myClass>();
  }

  public void printArray()
  {
    System.out.println("Slot 1: " + myArray.get(0));
    System.out.println("Slot 2: " + myArray.get(1));
    System.out.println("Slot 3: " + myArray.get(2));
  } 
}
```

I then created a "Main" class. Still getting the out of bounds error. It points to the printArray method is myClass2.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    myClass m = new myClass(); 
    myClass2 k = new myClass2(); 
    m.add2array(); 
    g.printArray(); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your constructor, you have declared new variables `randomR`, `randomT`, and `randomO` that are shadowing your existing instance variables of the same name.  Those instance variables aren't assigned, so they have the default value of `0`.  In your constructor, change

```
int randomR = (r.nextInt(10));
int randomT = (t.nextInt(10));
int randomO = (o.nextInt(10));
```

to

```
randomR = (r.nextInt(10));
randomT = (t.nextInt(10));
randomO = (o.nextInt(10));
```

Comment: this.randomR = (r.nextInt(10));
this.randomT = (t.nextInt(10));
this.randomO = (o.nextInt(10));

Answer (score 1):

I do not see you calling the `add2Array()` method any where. The reason you getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is due to the `myArray` not having any elements and the code executing `myArray.get(0)`.

Ensure to change whate @rgettman has suggested otherwise you will get 0 after fixing this issue I mentioned.

Call the `add2Array()` from the `myClass()` constructor

OR in another class

```
myClass m = new myClass();
m.add2Array();
m.printArray();
```

Not sure what you trying to achieve as the code is not that great. Also in Java good convention is to have class name starting with uppercase letter.

Comment: How would I call the add2array method in the other class? Do I just say add2array(); before I print out the arraylist?

Comment: You have not provided other class code. But you must be doing something like check answer.

Comment: I created a "Main" class and added your code, but I am still getting the out of bounds exception.... 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    myClass m = new myClass();
    myClass2 k = new myClass2();
    m.add2array();
    g.printArray();
}

Comment: Your code will not compile `g.printArray(); ` as variable g does not exist in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java `SecureRandom` inlace of `Random`.

Use the Java `SecureRandom` class and the method: `nextInt(int n)` which uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive).

This is a cryptographically secure PRNG that does not need to be seeded.

`SecureRandom` from [Class SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) and the `nextInt` method inherited from [Class Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt())

Answer (score -1):

If you call a new Random() with the same seed you'll always get the same answer.  Here's a way to get a psuedorandom integer:

```
 using System.Security.Cryptography;
 .
 .
 .

 public int Randominteger(int minValue, int maxValue)
 {
      RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypt = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
      byte[] fourbytes = new byte[4];
      crypt.GetBytes(fourbytes);
      return new Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(fourbytes, 0)).Next(minValue, maxValue);
 }
```

Comment: Is this a Jave solution, the OP specified Java in the tags.